Running Azure SDK on AWS Lambda
I'm trying to add Azure Speech SDK as a layer in a Lambda and I'm getting this:

[ERROR] OSError: /opt/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/azure/cognitiveservices/speech/libMicrosoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):

I checked the actual package that is working locally on my Windows but it doesn't have that file at all. I found that a .so is a sort of a Linux file equivalent to .dll but I don't know a thing about Linux and apparently Lambda is running on it.
Is there any way I should do this the right way? I'm not sure how I can manually download a Linux package.
